# Accumulated Distribution Line

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to learn some python and are currently doing a few stock market examples. However, I ran across something called an Accumulated Distribution Line(technical indicator) and tried to follow the mathematical expression for this until I reached the following line:

**ADL[i] = ADL[i-1] + money flow volume[i]**

Now. I have the money flow volume at index 8 and an empty table for the ADL at index 9 (index for rows in a csv file). How would I actually compute the mathematical expression above in python? (Currently using Python with Pandas)

Currently tried using the range function such as:

```
for i in range(1,stock["Money flow volume"])):

               stock.iloc[0,9] = stock.iloc[(i-1),9] + stock.iloc[i,8]
```

But I think I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that just looks like a cumulative sum with an unspecified base case, so I'd just use the built in [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) functionality.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(mfv=range(10)))
df['adl'] = df['mfv'].cumsum()
```

should do what you want relatively efficiently

Comment: In case you didn't know, nearly all technical indicators are built into modules you can import.  https://github.com/twopirllc/pandas-ta But if you are trying to learn python by doing, then building out yourself is a worthy cause.

Comment: it automatically runs over the whole Series, so there's no need to put it into a `for` loop.  try printing out `df` in my code before and after the `cumsum`.  running code in IPython or a Jupyter notebook can help to understand what's going on